# Does "_mm256_loadu_ps(ua_f)" have a maximum number of convertable "__m256"s?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avx

I'm trying to use AVX, and in two situations below:

- The first one: works well, meaning I can access its values.
- The second one: does not work, meaning I get segmentation fault when trying to access its values.

```cpp
__m256 bli[512];
for(size_t i =0; i < oc; i++){
    float ua_f[8];
    for(size_t j=0;j<8;j++){
        ua_f[j] = bias[i*8 + j];
    }
    bli[i] = _mm256_loadu_ps(ua_f);
}

_m256 mli[2100000];
for(size_t m=0; m < output_dim; m++){
    for(size_t n = 0; n<ic; n++){
        float ua_f[8];
        for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++){
            ua_f[i] = matrix[(i + 8*n)*output_dim + m];
        }
        
        size_t cal = m*ic +n;
        mli[cal] = _mm256_loadu_ps(ua_f);
    }
}
```

What is the difference? And how can I make second one work?

Comment: `_m256 mli[2100000];` allocates 64 megabytes on the stack, the platform limit is 8 megabytes on linux (usually, by default, on the main thread) and something like 2 megabytes on windows. Maybe you're running into a stack overflow issue

Comment: Loading a 32 byte vector from memory costs the same whether it's `_mm256_loadu_ps` on C `float` data or just accessing elements of a `__m256` array.  (Modulo differences in alignment, and of course cache locality).  Copying your input to a huge aligned array on the stack is not useful, just use `_mm256_loadu_ps` as required to access the original data.  If you need to transpose, use vector shuffles, or scalar code.  Vector reload of `ua_f` after scalar stores would cause a store-forwarding stall.  And the strided access-pattern to `matrix` is not efficient.

Comment: TL:DR: if you're thinking that it's helpful to "convert all your data to vectors before processing", that's not at all how it works.  `_mm256_loadu_ps` vs. `_mm256_load_ps` are mostly there to communicate alignment info to the compiler, and to deal with C's type system where each object normally has a single type, so accessing it as part of a `__m256` needs casting or this helper function.  (And BTW, yes it's strict-aliasing safe, `__m256*` can alias anything, but direct deref of it is like an aligned load.)